# What is preventing this web app from running?

Tags: java, web, build, module, glassfish

I'm very new to this and any help would be greatly appreciated. I tried to make a  new web app in net beans using existing source files. Whenever I run the project the build fails. I got the following output :
"GlassFish Server 4.1 is running.
In-place deployment at C:\Users\Timothy.Timothy-PC\Downloads\FowlTricks2\build\web
GlassFish Server 4.1, deploy, null, false
C:\Users\Timothy.Timothy-PC\Downloads\FowlTricks2\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1032: The module has not been deployed."

I've searched and found similar questions but I have been unable to determine what the problem is.
Here is my server log.

```
Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
Apr 19, 2015 5:00:16 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner createBundleProvisioner
INFO: Create bundle provisioner class = class com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.
Apr 19, 2015 5:00:16 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
WARNING: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.
Apr 19, 2015 5:00:16 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
WARNING: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.
Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishRuntime@11d68511 in service registry.
Found populator: com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.GFDomainXml
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : rootFolder=C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1\glassfish
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : templateDir=C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1\glassfish\lib\templates
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : src=C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1\glassfish\lib\templates\logging.properties
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : dest=C:\Users\Timothy.Timothy-PC\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.2\config\GF_4.1\domain1\config\logging.properties
Info:   Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1  (build 13)
Info:   Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter
Info:   Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
Info:   Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
Info:   Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.
Info:   Authorization Service has successfully initialized.
Info:   Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 282ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080]
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 3ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 5ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:4848]
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 2ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:3700]
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   Java security manager is disabled.
Info:   Entering Security Startup Service.
Info:   Loading policy provider com.sun.enterprise.security.provider.PolicyWrapper.
Info:   Security Service(s) started successfully.
Info:   Created HTTP listener http-listener-1 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8080
Info:   Created HTTP listener http-listener-2 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8181
Info:   Created HTTP listener admin-listener on host/port 0.0.0.0:4848
Info:   Created virtual server server
Info:   Created virtual server __asadmin
Info:   Setting JAAS app name glassfish-web
Info:   Virtual server server loaded default web module 
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Warning:   Ignore WEB-INF/sun-web.xml in archive /C:/Users/Timothy.Timothy-PC/Documents/HighSchoolSchedulePlanner/HSSP/build/web/, as WLS counterpart runtime xml WEB-INF/glassfish-web.xml is present in the same archive.
Info:   Initializing Mojarra 2.2.7 ( 20140610-1547 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.7@13362) for context '/HSSP'
Info:   HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.0.0.Final
Info:   Loading application [HSSP] at [/HSSP]
Info:   Loading application HSSP done in 9,218 ms
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   Loading application [IBM] at [/IBM]
Info:   Loading application IBM done in 357 ms
Info:   GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1  (13) startup time : Felix (4,667ms), startup services(10,432ms), total(15,099ms)
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 7ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:7676]
Info:   Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@99a78d7 as OSGi service registration: org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@257cc1fc.
Info:   Created HTTP listener http-listener-2 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8181
Info:   JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://172.25.52.155:8686/jndi/rmi://172.25.52.155:8686/jmxrmi
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 8ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]
Info:   Created HTTP listener http-listener-1 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8080
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 20ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080]
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Warning:   Ignore WEB-INF/sun-web.xml in archive /C:/Users/Timothy.Timothy-PC/Downloads/FowlTricks2/build/web/, as WLS counterpart runtime xml WEB-INF/glassfish-web.xml is present in the same archive.
Severe:   Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer prepare method
Severe:   java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid resource : jdbc/fowltricks__pm
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupDataSourceInDAS(ConnectorRuntime.java:593)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupPMResource(ConnectorRuntime.java:517)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.common.PersistenceHelper.lookupPMResource(PersistenceHelper.java:63)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.ProviderContainerContractInfoBase.lookupDataSource(ProviderContainerContractInfoBase.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.<init>(PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:108)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:142)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:223)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:510)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:230)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:925)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:434)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Invalid resource : jdbc/fowltricks__pm
    at org.glassfish.jdbcruntime.service.JdbcDataSource.validateResource(JdbcDataSource.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jdbcruntime.service.JdbcDataSource.setResourceInfo(JdbcDataSource.java:62)
    at org.glassfish.jdbcruntime.JdbcRuntimeExtension.lookupDataSourceInDAS(JdbcRuntimeExtension.java:136)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupDataSourceInDAS(ConnectorRuntime.java:589)
    ... 50 more
Severe:   Exception while preparing the app
Severe:   Exception during lifecycle processing
java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid resource : jdbc/fowltricks__pm
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupDataSourceInDAS(ConnectorRuntime.java:593)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupPMResource(ConnectorRuntime.java:517)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.common.PersistenceHelper.lookupPMResource(PersistenceHelper.java:63)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.ProviderContainerContractInfoBase.lookupDataSource(ProviderContainerContractInfoBase.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.<init>(PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:108)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:142)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:223)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:510)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:230)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:925)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:434)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Invalid resource : jdbc/fowltricks__pm
    at org.glassfish.jdbcruntime.service.JdbcDataSource.validateResource(JdbcDataSource.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jdbcruntime.service.JdbcDataSource.setResourceInfo(JdbcDataSource.java:62)
    at org.glassfish.jdbcruntime.JdbcRuntimeExtension.lookupDataSourceInDAS(JdbcRuntimeExtension.java:136)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupDataSourceInDAS(ConnectorRuntime.java:589)
    ... 50 more

Severe:   Exception while preparing the app : Invalid resource : jdbc/fowltricks__pm
com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Invalid resource : jdbc/fowltricks__pm
    at org.glassfish.jdbcruntime.service.JdbcDataSource.validateResource(JdbcDataSource.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jdbcruntime.service.JdbcDataSource.setResourceInfo(JdbcDataSource.java:62)
    at org.glassfish.jdbcruntime.JdbcRuntimeExtension.lookupDataSourceInDAS(JdbcRuntimeExtension.java:136)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupDataSourceInDAS(ConnectorRuntime.java:589)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupPMResource(ConnectorRuntime.java:517)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.common.PersistenceHelper.lookupPMResource(PersistenceHelper.java:63)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.ProviderContainerContractInfoBase.lookupDataSource(ProviderContainerContractInfoBase.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.<init>(PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:108)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:142)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:223)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:510)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:230)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:925)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:434)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like glassfish is trying to initialise a JPA entity manager pointing at a datasource in the server with JNDI name `jdbc/fowltricks__pm`.

Try to create a new datasource in the server and configure its JNDI name with this value (`jdbc/fowltricks__pm`) and restart the application.

Take a look at this documentation:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/ablih.html#SJSASEEAGablih

Comment: Thanks. I ran it again and now I'm getting this error, Severe:   Exception while deploying the app [FowlTricks2] : Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Connection could not be allocated because: Communications link failure

Comment: Ok. This error tells you that the connection pool can create any connection using the current configuration. Check that you have a database up and running and that your configuration is pointing at that database

Comment: I followed these instructions for connecting to a mysql database. https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/mysql.html#configuring

Comment: However, I get stuck as soon as I get to the part where I'm supposed to start the server. I'm assuming my server won't start for some reason. I downloaded xammp and hit the start button for mysql but whenever I go to the mysql server node under the databases node in netbeans and right click and select connect, I get a communications link error message.

Comment: Can I please get some help soon? I'm new to these things and I need to complete this project in approximately two weeks.

Comment: Are you sure your MySql is started in localhost and in the port you've configured? Check also your user and password. Once you can connect to the database, use those parameters in glassfish

Comment: MySql did not start. I've tried starting it but I keep getting an error when I try to start the service. The message is "Windows could not start MySQL server on local computer. Error: The process terminated unexpectedly"

Comment: Try to configure another database: Postgress, Oracle XE, or if you don't care the database itself, you can use an in-memory database, like H2. For example, follow this steps: https://keithrieck.wordpress.com/2010/02/23/h2-database-on-glassfish/

Comment: I need to use MySQL server though b/c I'm part of a team and thats what my groupmates are using. How can I get server to run?

Comment: Now the server is running and the user is connected but this error :Severe:   Exception while deploying the app [FowlTricks2] : Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Connection could not be allocated because: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
Error Code: 0
still persists .

Comment: Make sure your server is pointing at the correct host and port and it's using the correct user and password. Can you connect to the database with another tool like Netbeans?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make jdbc connection on the server named fowltricks not the jdbc/fowltricks__pm. It would solve the problem.